# Angular: automate copyright checking

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, sass

We are developing an angular application, which will be open-source. We add copyright in every file (at least .ts and .scss).

As we all are human, sometimes we forget these copyrights in new files.

Do you know any tool to automate the checking somewhere (in ng test, ng lint or from travis CI)?

Thx.

Comment: I know you can automate this check in SonarQube, but maybe a small library like [copyright-header](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyright-header) would work for you? (can apply copyright headers to any file tracked by git)

Answer (score 0):

I am finally using https://github.com/awjh/license-check-and-add which automates checking a license and adding it to every file.
It can be integrated to travis: the stage fails if a copyright is missing; it fits my needs.